# Silverlight DropShadow and Scaling

Tags: silverlight, transform, scale, shadow

In Silverlight, how one can scale the `DropShadowEffect`.

For eg. Following line creates the shadow, next to the rectangle object whose width and height is 100.

```
DropShadowEffect Color="Red" BlurRadius="0" Opacity="100" ShadowDepth="100" Direction="0"
```

Now I need to make the shadow of 90% or 110% instead of 100%.

Comment: how about you put question in your "question"

Comment: What are you talking about Denis? It's a perfectly obvious question!